# Reverse inclusion for function on $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be some set and $\mathcal{P}(X)$ its power set. For any $A\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$, define: $$f(A)=\{x\subseteq X:\;x\cap y\neq\emptyset,\;\forall y\in A\}$$
I have shown that $f$ is monotone decreasing, and that it has fixed points. The last part of the exercise whether:
$$x\in f(f(A))\Longrightarrow \exists y\in A\,\text{such that}\,y\subseteq x$$
Which is where I'm stuck. I've tried several small examples and it seems to be true, but my brain hurts if I try and write down $f(f(A))$ in set notation, so my hope is that there is a better way to look at this. I've noticed that $f(f(f(A)))=f(A)$, but this doesn't seem to be helpful. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ll use upper-case script letters for subsets of $\wp(X)$ and upper-case Roman letters for subsets of $X$.

HINT: The statement is indeed true. Let $\mathscr{A}\subseteq\wp(X)$; then $f(\mathscr{A})\subseteq\wp(X)$, and

$$f\big(f(\mathscr{A})\big)=\left\{Y\subseteq X:\forall Z\in f(\mathscr{A})\,(Y\cap Z\ne\varnothing)\right\}\;.$$

Now $Z\in f(\mathscr{A})$ iff $Z\cap A\ne\varnothing$ for each $A\in\mathscr{A}$, so $Y\in f\big(f(\mathscr{A})\big)$ iff $Y$ meets each subset of $X$ that meets each member of $\mathscr{A}$. Suppose that $Y\subseteq X$, and $A\setminus Y\ne\varnothing$ for each $A\in\mathscr{A}$.

- Use this to construct a member of $f(\mathscr{A})$ that is disjoint from $Y$, thereby showing that $Y\notin f\big(f(\mathscr{A})\big)$.